# Android If condition

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

In a android app, I click a button a flag is set to 1 and then I check if its set to 1 to do something. but its not working!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button1;
    TextView text1;
    int flag=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);;
        text1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = 1;
            }
        });


    if(flag == 1 ){
        text1.setText("Manoj Kumar S");

    }
}
```

This logic doesn't seem to work! Why?

Comment: can you put more of your code, to see if buttonFlag is an attribute, or a local variable, when are you doing your if condition...

Comment: if you are clicking on the button why you want to check if it was clicked? you have the OnClickListener.. this do the work for you.. just write the code of what you are want to do in the onClick method

Comment: The logic is pretty simple. I have a button, I click that I want  int buttonFlag = 0, to set change to buttonFlag =1 (This changes, I checked it using toast). 
Now I want to check if(buttonFlag == 1), I want to display a text on TextView. This is not happening !!!

Comment: post the original code

Comment: @Elior I have 5 buttons in my activity, so Only one button is going to do me a correct work remaining to do a wrong one. so this logic..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button1;
TextView text1;
int flag=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);;
    text1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = 1;
            updateTextView();
        }
    });
}

 private void updateTextView() {
   if(flag == 1 ){
    text1.setText("Manoj Kumar S");
   }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just move the line inside onClick

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button1;
TextView text1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);;
    text1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text1.setText("Manoj Kumar S");
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all executable code must be in a method.

```
if(flag == 1 ){

    text1.setText("Manoj Kumar S");

}
```

This code is not in a method, and will never be run.  Move it into a method, perhaps as Blackbelt has shown.

Answer (score 0):

I also think the logic isn't right there because buttons are event driven as stated by A--C.Try with some different things..

```
int flag=0;
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
              flag=1;
              test();
    }
});
private void test()
{
    if(flag==1)
        text1.setText("Do your stuff..");
}
```

Comment: Thanks,if you think it solves your problem then mark it as answer so that it may help those people who will face same problem like you..:)